# Ownerid field in task vf page not working

Tags: visualforce

We have created a simple vf page for Task object. when we display the ownerid in the input it is showing the "User & Partner User" as drop down options. We were expecting to show "User & Queue" as options (similar to the owner field on the standard task page).

Any reason why it is not showing the standard options for owner field when using vf page.

Appreciate the insights.

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" extensions="QMoneyTestTskCntrllr" deferLastCommandUntilReady="true" id="cPage" lightningStylesheets="True">
    <apex:form id="cForm">     
    
    <apex:pageBlock id="cBlock" title="Task Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:inputField id="f1" value="{!task.Type}"> </apex:inputField>
        <apex:inputField id="f2" value="{!task.ownerid}"> </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>


public with sharing class QMoneyTestTskCntrllr {
    public Task tskRec{get;set;}
    public QMoneyTestTskCntrllr (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        tskRec = (Task) controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Lightning or Classic? Did you define any queues for Task object?

Comment: In Lightning.. yes.. Queues are defined for Task object